# Python: numpy where command with if statement

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` that contains a column of dates in a string format like `'2011-12-13'` and a column of time, again in a string format, like `'15:40:00'`.

df

```
index                 date        time
2011-01-03 09:40:00   2011-01-03  09:40:00 
2011-01-03 09:45:00   2011-01-03  09:45:00 
2011-01-03 09:50:00   2011-01-03  09:50:00  
2011-01-03 09:55:00   2011-01-03  09:55:00 
2011-01-03 10:00:00   2011-01-03  10:00:00  
2011-01-03 10:05:00   2011-01-03  10:05:00
```

My objective is to create a colum `F0` in my dataframe where `F0=1` if the date belongs to any of these dates `('2011-01-26','2011-03-15', '2011-08-09', '2011-09-21', '2011-12-13')` and if the `time ='9:40:00'`.

I am trying to use the numpy function `where` as follow:

```
dates = ['2011-01-26','2011-03-15', '2011-08-09', '2011-09-21', '2011-12-13']

df['F1'] = np.where((df.date == any(dates) & (df.time== '9:40:00'), 1, 0))
```

I get this error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` Why? I don't know how to use the `any` function correctly.

I want to create multiple columns of `F2`, `F3`, and so on for other `time` interval like:

`df['F77'] = np.where((df.date == any(dates) & (df.time== '16:00:00'), 1, 0))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `where`.  Just use `isin` and apply your condition directly to the columns:

```
df['F1'] = df.date.isin(dates) & (df.time=='09:40:00')
```

Comment: fantastic @BrenBarn! I didn't know about `isin`